# Best way to calculate all ways certain variables can be assigned

Tags: python, list, combinations

I have a certain number of variables, each capable of attaining certain values, and I need to calculate all possible ways these variables can be assigned. For example, if I have -

```
variable_values = [[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

i.e. variable 1 can be `0`; variable 2 can be `0` or `1`; variable 3 can be `0`, `1` or `2`; and variable 4 can be `1` or `2`.

So, all possible value sets are -

```
possible_value_sets = [
    [0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 2, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 2, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 2],
    [0, 0, 1, 2],
    [0, 0, 2, 2],
    [0, 1, 0, 2],
    [0, 1, 1, 2],
    [0, 1, 2, 2],
]
```

What is the best way to calculate all possible value sets in python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> variable_values = [[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [1, 2]]
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.product(*variable_values))
[(0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 1, 2), (0, 0, 2, 1),
 (0, 0, 2, 2), (0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0, 2), (0, 1, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1, 2),
 (0, 1, 2, 1), (0, 1, 2, 2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import product,combinations
print [list(x) for x in (product(*variable_values))]
[[0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 2], [0, 0, 2, 1], [0, 0, 2, 2], [0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 2], [0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 1], [0, 1, 2, 2]]
```